# unique spline for different groups in a linear model (and no spline at all for one group)

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, survival, sas, splines

I have a problem that has puzzled me for a long time. It involves linear models and spline functions. I need to model "time since diagnosis" when some individuals never had a diagnosis. I use Poisson model where I have split time on age and time since diagnosis. The data set may look like this (with millions upon millions of rows,and with 95 % having no diagnosis ) :

SUBJECT       AGE    DIAGNOSIS    TIME_SINCE_DIAGNOSIS    EVENT/OUTCOME

1              30          A              0               0

1              31          A              1               0

1              32          A              2               1

2              45          B              0               0

2              46          B              1               0

103           22         NON            "0 or -"            0

103           23         NON            "0 or -"            0

.
.
.

You get the idea .. Now I want to have a model that looks something like this:

log ( OUTCOME ) = Spline( AGE ) + DIAGNOSIS * Spline( TIME_SINCE_DIAGNOSIS ) + offset ( logrisktime )

and then plotting the predicted risk for the different diagnoses of A and B as a function of " time since diagnosis " given that the diagnosis was at age = 30, and in the same plot for diagnosis = NON but then instead as a function of age ( with year since 30 on x-axis). I like to have both those with a diagnosis and those with diagnosis=NON in the same model to be able to do contrasts/linear combinations of effects.

Model and plot is done, but my problem is that the model above also creates a spline over the " time since diagnosis " for those who have no diagnosis (i.e. DIAGNOSIS = NON ). So, I would like to have a model of this type which I created indicator variables for the different diagnoses :

R: factor(A) factor(B) fator(NON)

SAS: class A B NON;

log ( OUTCOME ) = Spline ( AGE ) +  NON + A*Spline( TIME_SINCE_DIAGNOSIS ) + B*Spline ( TIME_SINCE_DIAGNOSIS ) + offset ( logrisktime )

Are you with me ?

So I want to create a unique spline of the variable "time since diagnosis" for each level of the variable "diagnosis" (which is done with diagnosis*spline(time_since_diagnosis) ), but with the exception that one level (those who had no diagnosis) does not to have any spline assigned.

Idea ?

Thanks,
Peter